# Laravel Middleware

Tags: php, laravel

Есть Laravel Middleware, который должен перенаправлять если пользователь не залогинен со след. содержимым:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   if (Auth::guest()) {
      redirect('/login');
   }
   return $next($request);
}
```

И роут:

```
Route::get('/solditems', ['middleware' => 'unauthorised', function(){}], 'PostController@sold');
```

Но middleware не срабатывает и вместо перенаправления я попадаю туда, куда ведет маршрут. В чём проблема?

Comment: а в `$routeMiddleware` все прописано?

Comment: В `$routeMiddleware` прописано `'unauthorised' => Middleware\IfUnAuthorized::class,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй прописать вот так

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   if (Auth::guest()) {
       return redirect('/login');
   }

   return $next($request);
 }
```